# Importing a GitHub project in Android Studio causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android

When I imported a GitHub project https://github.com/WaSuper/Mahjong into Android Studio, it shows this error:

```
Error:Module 'libactiveandroid' production: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/resources/ResourceFolderType
```

The GitHub project author gave me this library:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oNEXgr7JcgzhoPy9Uw1TJFKnByNljEiA/view?usp=sharing

But I don't know how to import the library file.

I am using Android Studio 4.1.3.

Comment: You can visit the Question and its Answers in this link. maybe help you to solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34413/2201814

Comment: Hi, Which build system does the project use, Maven or Gradle?  If it's Maven, this SO question shows how to install a jar into your local Maven repository, which you can then add as a dependency to your project.  Good luck! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project/22300875